# PHP 5.4 on IIS is adding slashes after quote automatically

Tags: php

My company recently switched to PHP. We have had no real issues until today. When I assign an string that has quotes inside it to a variable, the string will have slashes escaping the single quotes.

This is a one week old fresh install of 5.4. I read that 5.4 does not have magic quotes. I searched the php.ini and did not find anything with magic in the name, so it must not be on.

Example:

```
$sql = "Select Description from value where [Group]='auto_email_test'";
echo dbStr($sql, "0");
```

When I debug, the $sql will be

```
"Select Description from value where [Group]=\'auto_email_test\'";
```

Tried with no luck.

```
$sql = "Select Description from value where [Group]='auto_email_test'";
echo dbStr(stripslashes($sql), "0");
```

Why is php escaping my quotes right away? And why does stripslashes() not work to remove them?

EDIT: To Show dbStr();

```
/**
 *
 * Executes the $ImcomingSql query and returns the first cell in the first row
 *
 * @param string $_IncomingSql The sql query that you want to execute.
 * @param string $_DefaultValue The value to return if null.
 */
function dbStr($_IncomingSql, $_DefaultValue) {
$Result = Query(Conn, $_IncomingSql);
if ($Result !=0)
{
    $Rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($Result);
    if ($Rows) 
    {
        $Row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
        $Result = $Row[0];
        return $Result;
    }
}
return $_DefaultValue;
}
```

Comment: so what is this `dbStr()` function doing? It's not a standard php function, so most likely it's replicating magic_quotes (which is an incredibly stupid thing to do)

Comment: It is very simple. Just runs query and returns firs cell in first row. nothing to do with string formatting.

Comment: Also, I can debug and look the the definition of $sql and it wuill have the slashes. It doesn't have to go into the function.

Comment: PHP has no clue what sql is. it would not mangle a string and magically change `'` to `\'`, just because it MIGHT be sql... Trivial checK: elminate the dbStr() call. just `echo $sql`. You'll find that your string is unchanged, which means it is dbStr doing something.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's the php tools debugging program. Because if I echo out the string, the slashes are not there. But when I have the $sql going into the function, the debugging shows the slashes on the $sql definition.

Comment: exactly. so look at what that function is doing. We obviously can't...

Comment: I edited my question to show dbstr, it does nothing to my string.

Comment: Welp, no idea... but I do know PHP will **NOT** mangle a string on you. Whatever is causing your quotes to get escaped, it's NOT something built into PHP, unless for some reason magic_quotes **IS** on. have you checked `phpinfo()`? php can use multiple .ini files and the magic quotes setting may be stored somewhere entirely different than the main .ini file

Comment: I used code to see what php.ini is loaded and searched that file, I did not find anything with "magic" or "magic_quotes".